# Silverstripe: partialMatchFilter and "&"

Tags: silverstripe

I have a client that wants to be able to pick several things off the Silverstripe tag cloud widget.

So, using jQuery, I prepare a string containing all the selected tags which I then pass to a Silverstripe function.

```
if($_GET["selectedTags"]){

  $selectedTagString = $_GET["selectedTags"];
  $selectedTagString = substr($selectedTagString, 0, strlen($selectedTagString) -1);

  $tagArray = explode("|", $selectedTagString);

  $blogEntries = DataObject::get("BlogEntry")->filter(array("Tags:PartialMatch" => $tagArray));

  return $blogEntries->renderWith(array("blogSearchResults"));
  }
}
```

And it works quite well.

EXCEPT for tags that have an "&" in them, like "Otago & Southland", where the search fails and nothing is retrieved.

Looking at the generated SQL, everything seems to be fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "SiteTree_Live"."ClassName", "SiteTree_Live"."Created", 
.
.
.
"BlogEntry_Live"."BlogEntryThumbnailID", "SiteTree_Live"."ID", CASE WHEN "SiteTree_Live"."ClassName" IS NOT NULL THEN "SiteTree_Live"."ClassName" ELSE 'SiteTree' END AS "RecordClassName" FROM "SiteTree_Live" LEFT JOIN "Page_Live" ON "Page_Live"."ID" = "SiteTree_Live"."ID" LEFT JOIN "BlogEntry_Live" ON "BlogEntry_Live"."ID" = "SiteTree_Live"."ID" WHERE ("BlogEntry_Live"."Tags" LIKE '%southland & otago championships%') AND ("SiteTree_Live"."ClassName" IN ('BlogEntry')) ORDER BY "SiteTree_Live"."Sort" ASC
```

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: @FinBoWa - You are correct. Thanks for pointing that out. I've removed my incorrect statement.

Answer (score 1):

Are the tags stored using `&amp;`  in the db? Then you first should html encode your string.